# Getting n column where values are less than m

Tags: python, numpy

###### I know I can use code below to get `n` column

```py
import numpy as np

x: np.ndarray = np.array([ [0.1, 0.5], [0.7, 0.4], [0.6, 0.9] ])
first_column: np.ndarray = x[:, 0]
```

###### And also I could use code below to get values below `0.5`

```py
import numpy as np

x: np.ndarray = np.array([ [0.1, 0.5], [0.7, 0.4], [0.6, 0.9] ])
values_below_05: np.ndarray = x[x < 0.5]
```

#### Is there any way to get `n` column where data in this column are less than `0.5` from numpy array in such a this way:

```py
import numpy as np

x: np.ndarray = np.array([ [0.1, 0.5], [0.7, 0.4], [0.6, 0.9] ])
# desired way
values_below_05_from_first_column = x[:, 0][x < 0.5]
```

###### Instead of writing:

```py
import numpy as np

x: np.ndarray = np.array([ [0.1, 0.5], [0.7, 0.4], [0.6, 0.9] ])
first_column: np.ndarray = x[:, 0]
values_below_05: np.ndarray = first_column[first_column < 0.5]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do this:-

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0.1, 0.5], [0.7, 0.4], [0.6, 0.9]])
b = a[a[:, 0] < 0.5]
print(b)
```

Which will result in:-

[[0.1 0.5]]